# Why am I getting an IndexError: list index out of range when my code appears to be within the range?

Tags: python

I was coding a project called "My Countdown Calendar". I was almost done and so I gave what I had so far a test run. I ended up getting this error.
Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from datetime import date, datetime

def gete():
    liste = []
    with open('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            currente = line.split(',')

            eventd = datetime.strptime(currente[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
            currente[1] = eventd
            liste.append(currente)
        return liste
def daysbd(date1, date2):
    timeb = str(date1-date2)
    numberofd = timeb.split(' ')
    return numberofd[0]

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, bg='black')
c.pack()
c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='w', fill='orange', font = 'Arial 28 bold underline', text = 'My Countdown Calendar')


events = gete()
today = date.today()

for event in events:
    eventn = event[0]
    daysu = daysbd(event[1], today)
    display = 'It is %s days until %s ' % (daysu, eventn)
    c.create_text(100, 100, anchor='w', fill='lightblue',\
                  font = 'Arial 28 bold ', text = display)
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: please post the error code

Comment: My guess is you have a line in the file with no `,`, so `currente[1]` is out of range.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Osprey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\countdown_calendar.py", line 28, in <module>
    for event in gete():
  File "C:\Users\Osprey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\countdown_calendar.py", line 11, in gete
    eventd = datetime.strptime(currente[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That is my error code

Comment: Barmar my file has 2 lines in it.

Comment: Those lines are dates and events and they are separated by commas

Comment: Maybe you have an empty line. You should almost always add `if not line.strip(): continue` to such a for loop over the lines.

Comment: you mean add that loop in the def gete()?

Comment: Thank you Tim Hoffmann your solution fixed my errors. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply add a check to your code, right after you split the line, to check that `len(currente)` is >= 2?  My guess is that it will fail for some line, and then you'll know exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @Osprey I've created a general answer, so that the solution is easier to find.

Comment: http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing a text file, you'll almost always want to skip empty lines. Here's an idomatic pattern for this:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    # process line
```

If your file format depends on whitespace on the non-empty lines, you can join lines 2 and 3 to `if not line.strip()`.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and appreciated.